# kendi UI angular snippets widget eventing

Tags: angular, kendo-ui

I've seen that the kendoUI uses the snippet dropdownlist for other languages, and their website does have documentation for this, but in the angular section, it is not mentioned.

I have seen this widget used in angular applications but I cannot find the supported events.

Has anyone used this?

Comment: I want to capture the event where an item is selected and then edit the textbox.

Comment: Any updates on this ?

Answer (score 0):

You should show your code for a better understanding of what your are doing, but I will try my guess here:

Try to bind the event [`select`](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/dropdownlist/events/select) in the widget initialization, that you are probably doing like [this](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/AngularJS/introduction#event-handlers).

[Demo](https://dojo.telerik.com/ULaguLOF)